# How can I scale a PNG so it takes the height of the page?

Tags: graphics

I want a PNG to be as big as possible on a page without to be cut.
Is it a way such as the `[width=\textwidth]` to do the same with the height ?

```
\begin{figure}[htbp!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../figs/Image}
\end{figure}
```

With this example, if the height of the picture is bigger than the height of the page then the image is cut to fit in the page. How can I do to scale the picture so that it just fit in the page with the caption?

Maybe something like `[height=\textheight]` ?

Comment: I know I didn't put a MWE, but I didn't get how to do it with an image... Sorry

Comment: package `mwe` provides example images ;-)

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84527

Comment: `height=\textheight` is legal yes, did you try it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes it works... I tried it just after editing the question...

Comment: Also give a try to `keepaspectratio`. If you use it with `height=\textheight,width=\textwidth`, it will fit the image. Note that you don't have any guarantee that the label will fit as well with this method.

Comment: Also related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183699/fit-tikzpicture-to-page-width-or-height-using-macros/183712?s=1|0.2667#183712